# glClearColor is tinting my entire texture?

Tags: opengl

I'm taking a simple OpenGL app I had before that had an Icosahedron and changing it over to render to a texture and then draw that texture on screen. Somehow, during the rendering to texture, when I call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` my entire texture is being tinted by my `glClearColor`. Here's the entirety of what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void SetupRenderTarget();
void EnableLighting();
GLuint LoadProgram(char*, char*);
void draw();
float UpdateDelta();
unsigned long getFileLength(ifstream&);
GLuint compileshader(char* file, GLenum shader_type);
int loadshader(char*, GLchar**, unsigned long*);

GLuint quad_vertexbuffer;
GLuint frame = 0;
GLuint FrameBuffer = 0;
GLuint texID = 0;
GLuint timeID = 0;
GLuint renderedTexture;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);

    glewInit();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);
    EnableLighting();
  SetupRenderTarget();

  frame = LoadProgram((char*)"passthrough.shader", (char*)"framebuffer.shader");
  texID = glGetUniformLocation(frame, "renderedTexture");
  timeID = glGetUniformLocation(frame, "time");

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void SetupRenderTarget() {
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &FrameBuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuffer);
  glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 300, 300, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

  GLuint DepthBuffer;
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &DepthBuffer);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, DepthBuffer);
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 300, 300);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, DepthBuffer);

  glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);
  GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
  glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

  if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    cout << "Frame Buffer Error!" << endl;
    return;
  }

  cout << "Frame Buffer Setup" << endl;
}

void EnableLighting() {
    float light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float light_position[] = { -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

GLuint LoadProgram(char* vertex, char* fragment) {
  GLuint ProgramObject = 0;
  GLuint v, f;
  if (vertex != 0) v = compileshader(vertex, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  if (fragment != 0) f = compileshader(fragment, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    ProgramObject = glCreateProgram();
  if (v != -1) glAttachShader(ProgramObject, v);
  if (f != -1) glAttachShader(ProgramObject, f);

    cout << "Linking Shader..." << endl;
    glLinkProgram(ProgramObject);

    cout << "Done!" << endl;
    return ProgramObject;
}

GLuint compileshader(char* file, GLenum shader_type) {
  cout << "Loading Shader: " << file << endl;
  char* src;
  unsigned long src_length = 0;
  int err = loadshader(file, &src, &src_length);
  if (err != 0) return -1;// something went wrong

  cout << "Creating Shader..." << endl;
  GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);
  cout << "Loading Shader..." << endl;
  glShaderSourceARB(shader, 1, (const char**)&src, (const int*)&src_length);
  cout << "Compiling Shader..." << endl;
  glCompileShaderARB(shader);
  delete[] src;

  GLint compiled;
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
  if (!compiled) {
    GLint blen = 0;
    GLsizei slen = 0;

    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &blen);
    if (blen > 1) {
      GLchar* compiler_log = (GLchar*)malloc(blen);
      glGetInfoLogARB(shader, blen, &slen, compiler_log);
      cout << "Compiler Log:" << endl << compiler_log << endl;
      free(compiler_log);
    } else {
      cout << "Compile error but could not get log!" << endl;
    }
    return -1;
  }
  return shader;
}

void draw() {
  static float mytime = 0;
    float delta = UpdateDelta();
  mytime += delta;

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuffer);
  glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);

  glLoadIdentity();
  float x = 0.5f;
  glClearColor(x, x, x, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);

    glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
    glutSolidIcosahedron();

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);

  glUseProgram(frame);
  glUniform1i(texID, 0);
  glUniform1f(timeID, mytime * 10);

  glLoadIdentity();
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
  glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
  glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
  glEnd();

  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glUseProgram(0);

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

float UpdateDelta() {
    static int time_since_start = 0;
    static int last = 0;
    time_since_start = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

    float ret = (time_since_start - last) / 1000.0f;
    last = time_since_start;
    return ret;
}

unsigned long getFileLength(ifstream& file) {
    if (!file.good()) return 0;

    unsigned long pos = (unsigned long)file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)file.tellg();
    file.seekg(ios::beg);

    return len;
}

int loadshader(char* filename, GLchar** ShaderSource, unsigned long* len) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename, ios::in); // opens as ASCII!
    if (!file) return -1;

    *len = getFileLength(file);

    if (*len == 0) return -2;   // Error: Empty File

    *ShaderSource = (GLchar*) new char[*len + 1];
    if (*ShaderSource == 0) return -3;   // can't reserve memory

                                         // len isn't always strlen cause some characters are stripped in ascii read...
                                         // it is important to 0-terminate the real length later, len is just max possible value... 
    (*ShaderSource)[*len] = 0;

    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (file.good()) {
        (*ShaderSource)[i] = file.get();       // get character from file.
        if (!file.eof()) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    (*ShaderSource)[i] = 0;  // 0-terminate it at the correct position
    file.close();

    return 0; // No Error
}
```

I'm partially following [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) and using it's shaders.

passthrough.shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
  UV = (vertexPosition_modelspace.xy + vec2(1, 1)) / 2.0;
}
```

and framebuffer.shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 UV;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D renderedTexture;
uniform float time;

void main() {
  color = texture(renderedTexture, UV.xy).rgb; // no change to image
  //color = texture(renderedTexture, UV + 0.005*vec2(sin(time + 300.0*UV.x), cos(time + 300.0*UV.y))).xyz; // wibbly-wobbly version from tutorial
}
```

Ok, I know that's a lot of code so here's the short and sweet as I understand what's going on.

`SetupRenderTarget` creates a Color and a Depth buffer the same size as my window (300x300).

`EnableLighting` just positions and lights the scene. It seems to be working fine and is unrelated to the question other than giving an interesting thing to look at.

`LoadProgram` reads in vector and fragment source files, compiles them, puts them in the same program, links that program and returns the program id if all went well using `compileshader` and `loadshader`. It also seems to be working correctly.

`draw` is where the meat of the problem is happening. I set it to use the `FrameBuffer`, I set the clear color (using x is because I'm so tired of changing each parameter's value from 0.0 to 1.0 and back again), I clear, I set the color for my icosahedron, and now the scene is fully rendered in the frame.

Then I start using my program and switch over to the actual "draw to screen" frame buffer of 0, I clear that buffer with black (this clear doesn't seem to matter what I set it to, it has no impact), I draw a white quad without lighting and revert the lighting and programs back for the next loop.

I get no compiler errors or warnings any time during the execution of this. The problem is when I call `glClear()` when I'm rendering the icosahedron to the frame buffer, that color tints the entire texture. I would like to set my `x` var to 0 so that I have a black background behind a vibrant green shape but the entire texture goes black.

Here's a few images generated by only changing that `x` var:

x = 1.0f;

[image: x = 1]

x = 0.5f;

[image: x = 0.5]

x = 0.1f;

[image: x = 0.1]

To my understanding, the background behind the shape should be darkening to reflect the clear color but not the shape itself. It should remain just as vibrant a green as it appears in the first image.

Why would my clear color affect how the icosahedron is drawn and how do I fix it?

I'm compiling using Visual Studio with NupenGL libraries on Win7 x64 and `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` says 4.3.

Comment: I'm mostly an ES person but this is quite a fixed/programmable hybrid, so: what guarantees does `glutSolidIcosahedron` make about texturing? It's probably not the cause but I'd want to rule out that you're technically invalidly having your framebuffer object bound at the same time as is "is possible" that its texture may be sampled (the test is possibility, not necessarily actual sampling). Which is a cause of undefined behaviour. See 4.4.3 of http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt for the original rules.

Comment: @Tommy According to [this page](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node80.html) glut Solid shapes all have Normals but only the teapot has Texture coordinates. Of course it hasn't updated since 1996...

Comment: You can be sure that this is not a problem by removing the call to: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); I've been looking at the code for a while but I can't see an obvious problem either, though I'm not very well versed in "old" opengl. I've upvoted your question.

Comment: I'm not sure why but yeah removing `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` from the main method fixes the issue for me. Know that we know the problem and solution, I hope somebody can come up with the why.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using shaders when drawing the ICO you use the default pipeline. `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` instructs the pipeline to use texturing. So which texture have you bound?

Turns out you bound the texture you render to,  `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);`, and never unbound it by calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);`. So you are drawing an ICO which is fetching its texture data from what you are drawing to, which at that time only contains the background color `(x,x,x)`.

Technically, I think reading from a texture while you are writing to it results in undefined behavior. So even if the behavior was "correct" this time, don't count on this behavior to work consistently.

As an addition, you should know that `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);` causes your texture to blend with the color, so without that call the ICO (I think) wouldn't be green at all!